Getting exception System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.when launching chrome browser in selenium
I am currently working on selenium automation.Seeing below error when running
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
Installed below nugets
Selenium Webdriver->4.24.0
selenium.webdriver.chromedriver->129.0.6668.5800
Chrome browser installed ->version 129.0.6668.59(official build 64 bit)
Getting exception when running the test :
TestMethod threw exception:
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
chrome browser to launch and navigate to url

system level exception there...  Can you include more of your code?  Are you displaying an interface (GUI?)?  Using any robot-like automation code? at the OS level?

Following code worked with latest chrome
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
           driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
driver.Navigate();
Thread.Sleep(6000);
driver.Quit();


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
